# C++ program for conversion of infix expression from user through command line to postfix using stack

Tags: c++, data-structures

Can some help me in the following

Write a c++ program that takes an infix expression from user through command line and convert it into a postfix expression. Stack data structure should use for the implementation of this task.

Regards,
Abdul Nasir

Comment: What have you got so far? Where do your have a problem you need help with?

Comment: Why can't do you do your own homework?

Answer (score 3):

[Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

That's all the help you're getting. If you have a particular problem then state it -- we aren't going to do your homework for you.